Error 403: Requests from referer are blocked when using YouTube API with referer restrictions
I’m working on a project where I’m using the YouTube Data API v3 to retrieve channel data. However, I’m encountering an error when making a request:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Requests from referer \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Requests from referer \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "API_KEY_HTTP_REFERRER_BLOCKED",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "consumer": "projects/480613114246",
          "service": "youtube.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

This is my code:
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchVideos = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=${apiKey}&channelId=${channelId}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=3`
                );
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Error al obtener los videos');
                }
                const data = await response.json();
                setVideos(data.items);
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.error('Error al obtener los videos:', error);
            }
        };
        fetchVideos();
    }, [channelId]);

I’ve set up my YouTube API key in the Google Cloud Console with referer restrictions to allow requests only from the following domains:
https://www.spacetiger.me/
https://space-tiger-tarot-db.vercel.app/
http://localhost:5173/  
http://localhost:5173/* 
https://www.spacetiger.me/  
https://www.spacetiger.me/* 
space-tiger-tarot-db.vercel.app 
spacetiger.me/  
spacetiger.me/*

But I’m still getting the error mentioned, and I’m not sure what’s causing it. I’ve checked the following:
1- The URLs I’ve set are correct and match the domains from where I’m making the requests.
2- I’ve made sure the requests are coming from the correct domains using https://.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions on what could be causing this error? I would really appreciate any help or advice on how to resolve it.
It’s one of my first projects, I’m using React + Vite and deployed it to Vercel. I set up the API a few hours ago, and it was working fine, but suddenly it stopped working. I can't find any related errors in the Google Cloud console. The API key is in my .env file and in the environment variables on Vercel. I don't see anywhere that says my API key is blocked or disabled. I restricted the API to work with YouTube Data API v3.
Thanks!

please edit your question and include your code.

@LindaLawton-DaImTo done!
